# jQuery form on ready/load does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ready

I have this 'template' code (just for example):

```
$(document).on("<EVENT>", "form", function() {
    $(this).find(".input input").each(function() {
        var required = $(this).attr("required");
        var checkField = $(this).closest("tr").children(".check");
        var errorField = $(this).closest("tr").children(".errormessage");
        if (required != undefined) {
            $(checkField).css("color", "#FFFF00");
            $(checkField).html("&#x2718;");
            $(errorField).css("color", "#FFFF00");
            $(errorField).html("(Required)");
        }
        else {
            $(checkField).css("color", "#FFFF00");
            $(checkField).html("&#x2714;");
            $(errorField).css("color", "#000000");
            $(errorField).html("");
        }
    });
});
```

When `<EVENT>` is for example `click` or `mouseover`, it just works as expected.
However it refuses to work on an `ready` or `load` event, any clue why?

Comment: There is no `ready` or `load` event for a form. The `form` is ready, when the `document` is ready. Have a read of the [.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) docs for jQuery.

Comment: the `$(document).on(...)` is itself called on page load and i`m not sure why you want to trigger it automatically, if you want to execute some js code on page load then enclose those inside `$(document).on(...)`

Comment: ready or load is just for the document, what you expect by form load?

Comment: wat are you doin and why dont you write your mark up directly rather than complicating it unnecessarily..

Comment: I am trying to preprocess a form when it is being "loaded"/"rendered", independent of whether it is directly loaded or comes in via HTML code out of an AJAX call.

Comment: @skiwi there is no event for that except maybe if you look to kind of DOM mutation observer but in most case, this is a bad approach. Just call a function or trigger a custom event when you add new element

Answer (score 1):

From http://api.jquery.com/on/

> In all browsers, the load, scroll, and error events (e.g., on an  element) do not bubble. In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, the paste and reset events do not bubble. Such events are not supported for use with delegation, but they can be used when the event handler is directly attached to the element generating the event.